# Mysql Event not showing

Tags: mysql

I created an event, everything works fine. Event_Scheduler=on, all is perfectc

But the event is not giving results, I tried select * from events, it's empty but when I try show create event... it appears.

Any idea?

Comment: did you mean `show events;` since `select * from events` will require a table called `events` on the selected DB. If you are looking at the information schema then there should be a table called `events` and you may do as `select * from information_schema.events`

Comment: I create the events table then my event but it s not appearing in the table

Comment: Show events, too.. not showing any event

Comment: Meaning event is not created, update the question and add the event scheduler that you have added. Also after setting `Event_Scheduler=on` you will need to restart the mysql server.

Comment: When you say you create an event table, you mean just for an event you programmed to write to that table, yes?  You didn't create a table called EVENTS hoping that would work for event handling?  Like if you make that table and do SHOW EVENTS, NOTHING will ever list because its a table and not an event.